# How to call API as promise in REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, promise

I am getting the following error when I run myu application and click on a submit button,

```
   React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by SideBarItemTemplateWithData. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

  Previous render            Next render
  ------------------------------------------------------
  1. useContext                 useContext
  2. useMemo                    useState
```

My SideBarItemTemplateWithData,

```
RoomListRowProps): ReactElement {
   const { sidebar } = useLayout();
    let priority:any;
    let userRoomId:any;
    let data:any;
    const href = roomCoordinator.getRouteLink(room.t, room) || '';
    const title = roomCoordinator.getRoomName(room.t, room) || '';
    if (room && room.v && room.v._id) {
       userRoomId = room.v._id;
    }
if (room && room.priorityId) {
    data = useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
}
if (data && data.value && data.value.name) {
    priority = data.value.name.toLowerCase();
}

const {
    lastMessage,
    hideUnreadStatus,
    hideMentionStatus,
    unread = 0,
    alert,
    userMentions,
    groupMentions,
    tunread = [],
    tunreadUser = [],
    rid,
    t: type,
    cl,
} = room;
<SideBarItemTemplate
        userId={userRoomId}
        priority={priority}
        is='a'
/>
```

I am getting the error when I run the above code but when I comment the following line it is working fine,

```
if (room && room.priorityId) {
    data = useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
}
```

The below line returns a promise,

```
  useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
```

Can anyone suggest me to how can I modify it o that the issue will be resolved. Thanks

useEndPoint code,

```
   export const useEndpoint = <TMethod extends Method, TPath extends PathFor<TMethod>>(
      method: TMethod,
      path: TPath,
  ): EndpointFunction<TMethod, MatchPathPattern<TPath>> => {
  const { callEndpoint } = useContext(ServerContext);

  return useCallback((params: any) => callEndpoint(method, 
  path, params), [callEndpoint, path, method]);
  };
```

How to use useEndPoint,

```
const sendEmailCode = useEndpoint('POST', '/v1/users.2fa.sendEmailCode');
await sendEmailCode({ emailOrUsername });
```

My Code,

```
    const priorityData = useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
if (room && room.v && room.v._id) {
    userRoomId = room.v._id;
}

const onClickResendCode = async (): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        let priorityVal = '';
        let data = await priorityData();
        if (data && data.name) {
            priorityVal = data.name.toLowerCase();
        }
        return priorityVal;
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

priority = onClickResendCode();
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I modify the api call

Comment: Can you show us the code for useEndpoint? How to fix it will depend on what that code does.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not about the promise, is about the order of the hook. In React you must keep the order of all your hook. You should not use your hook in a if or a loop.

This is the error.

```js
if (room && room.priorityId) {
    data = useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
}
```

it should be

```js
data = useEndpoint('GET', `/v1/livechat/priorities/${room.priorityId}`);
```

You can use `if` in the `callEndpoint` function, which is not a react hook.

Comment: @Hao0Jung Hsieh, I had updated as per your answer and I want to store priority value in a variable can you please update based on my code.